# Replacing element of array with data from another table using QGIS Expression

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, string, replace, qgis-expression

How to do it in QGIS or QGIS Expression to replace the element of an array(cell value) of a table with a new value taken from another table (which contains the list of the element and its corresponding new value), see image below:

[image: 1]

Comment: All the fields are of type string?

Comment: By the way: as a general principle, I would **always** avoid spaces in Layer names (`Table 2`) and field names (`Existing Data`) - and any other names like filnames etc.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the order of `Old element` and `New Element` are the same, you can use this expression on `Table 1`:

```
array_get(
    aggregate(
        'Table 2',         -- the name of the layer with the field `New element`
        'array_agg',
        "uuid_trgt"        -- the name of the field in `Table 2` containing `New element`
    ),
    array_find(
        aggregate(
            @layer,        -- the current layer (`Table 1`)
            'array_agg',   
            "uuid_src"     -- the name of the field in the current layer (`Table 1`) containing `Old element`
        ),
        "uuid_src"         -- the name of the field in the current layer (`Table 1`) containing `Old element`
    )
)
```

[image]

The expression makes an array of all the values in the `Old element` field, then for each row of Table 1, finds the position in the array of the current value of `Old element` and retrieves the corresponding item from an array of `New element` values.

Answer (score 0):

Use this expression to find the corresponding value, regardless of the attribute's order:

```
attribute (
    get_feature(
        'Table 2',
        'Old element',
        "Existing Data"
    ),
    'New Element'
)
```

**Explanation:**

1. Use function [`get_feature()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#get-feature) to return the feature of `Table 2` where the field `Old element` matches the attribute value of `Existing Data` in `Table 1`
2. then use [`attribute()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#attribute) to return the value of the attribute `New Element` of this feature.

*By the way: try to avoid names with a space in it, as in some contexts, that can cause problems.*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic use case for [table joins](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#sec-joins): Enter layer properties of `Table 1` > Tab <kbd>Joins</kbd>, create a new join (green <kbd>+</kbd> icon) and define the table to join and the attributes from both tables that match.

*Options: select which fields to join and if the names of the joined fields should get a prefix:*

[image]

[image]